# Previous and updated releases of Arduino IDE are not be able to start on Win 8.1 x64

Tags: arduino-ide, ide, windows

I have tried to install many versions of IDE, but non of them has started successfully. There is just the logo of the program shows up and then nothing happens.
My laptop: Toshiba Satellite C50-A630
The releases I have installed: 1.6.12 , 1.6.13, 1.0.6

Comment: Which Java Version you got installed?

Comment: Delete your preferences.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with various IDE versions. Deleting the preferences.txt solved the problem for me.